# Debugging Ember.js from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

When I try debug Ember.js from chrome browser, its breakpoint for application.js only persists and rest are removed on page refresh by pressing f5.

I have enabled "Log XMLHTTP Requests" and "Preserve Log Upon Navigation" in console tab. Still the problem is there ..

Any help ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an alternative you can set the breakpoints in your code.
javascript:

```
debugger;
```

handlebars:

```
{{debugger}}
```